# Javascript function remove from position in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array:

```
var myArray = [12, 11, 13, 18, 30, 51, 21, 18, 20];
```

I need to remove each 3rd item from the array and add it to another array.

The final result should be:

```
var myArray = [12, 11 18, 30, 21, 18];

var secondArray = [13, 51, 20];
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Just use a good old fashioned `for` loop and reset it it after each 3rd item. Have another array and keep adding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate over the array and splice every 3rd element and push to the second array.

```js
var myArray = [12, 11, 13, 18, 30, 51, 21, 18, 20];
var secondArray = [];
for (var i = 2; i < myArray.length; i += 2) {
  secondArray.push(myArray[i]);
  myArray.splice(i, 1);
}

console.info('myArray', myArray)
console.info('secondArray', secondArray)
```

Comment: Change the start index to `2` and increment by `2`. Also, `splice` returns an array so you should use `concat`

Comment: change increment to `i+=2`

Answer (score 0):

I do not like example with splicing source array, because splicing is a long operation and in large arrays / multiple operations it will be not so effective. I think you should create new arrays and don't mind.

```
const arraysList = myArray.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        acc.second.push(item);
    } else {
        acc.first.push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, { first: [], second: [] })

console.log(arraysList.first); // [12, 11 18, 30, 21, 18]
console.log(arraysList.second); // [13, 51, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [12, 11, 13, 18, 30, 51, 21, 18, 20];

var newArray1 = [];
var newArray2 = [];
myArray.forEach(function(value,index){
  if((index + 1) % 3 === 0){
    newArray1.push(value);
  }
  else {
    newArray2.push(value);
  }
});

console.log(newArray1); // Stores element at index 3 in the original array
console.log(newArray2); // Stores element at index other than 3 in the original array
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#reduce` the original array into 2 new arrays:

```js
const myArray = [12, 11, 13, 18, 30, 51, 21, 18, 20];

const [without3rdItems, with3rdItems] = myArray.reduce((arrs, n, i) => {
  const arr = (i + 1) % 3 ? 0 : 1;
  
  arrs[arr].push(n);
  
  return arrs;
}, [[], []]);

console.log(without3rdItems.join());
console.log(with3rdItems.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [12, 11, 13, 18, 30, 51, 21, 18, 20];
var b = [ ];
var l = a.length;
for(i = 2; i < l; i += 2){
    b.push(a[i]);
    a.splice(i, 1);
    l--;
}
console.log("Array a: ", a);
console.log("Array b: ", b);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.